# Controller in its own dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am not aware of latest release of angularjs. I saw a piece of code like below

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('myApp', [myApp]);

function myApp() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.title = 'Customers';
      vm.customers = [
        {name: 'Haley'}, {name: 'Ella'}, {name: 'Landon'}, {name: 'John'}
        ];
    };
```

instead of code i used to write earlier like

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('myApp', function($scope){
      $scope.title = 'Customers';
      $scope.customers = [
        {name: 'Haley'}, {name: 'Ella'}, {name: 'Landon'}, {name: 'John'}
        ];
});
```

So why are we injecting the functionality required for the controller? what advantage does it provide. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That controller is not being used in its own dependency injection.

This is simply a syntax for defining a controller:

```
.controller('controllerName', [
    'dependency1', 
    'dependency2', 
    function (dependency1, dependency2) {
    }
]);
```

This approach allows specifying the names for the dependencies explicitly and prevents your dependencies from getting messed up if you minify the code.

In the case of your example, there are no dependencies, and the function is being referenced as a variable instead of being included inline.

It's also using the "controller as" syntax (where the controller refers to itself as `this`) instead of using the `$scope` service, but that is a completely separate matter.

You could also modify your second example to work the same way:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('myApp', ['$scope', myApp]);

function myApp($scope){
      $scope.title = 'Customers';
      $scope.customers = [
        {name: 'Haley'}, {name: 'Ella'}, {name: 'Landon'}, {name: 'John'}
        ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What it does is instead of calling an anonymous function from controller its separate the function from the controller and call the function.In this case, function name is `myApp`

reason to call it with square brackets is when you are using angular minify version, dependency injector unable to identify the dependency so it produces an error.

In order to identify the relevant dependency by the injector, angular allow you to write dependency as string array when you are initializing controller. Since there is no dependency in this example only empty square brackets appear.

If you have a dependency, let's say `$scope` then you need to inject it like this

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('myApp', ['$scope',myApp]);

function myApp($scope) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.title = 'Customers';
      vm.customers = [
        {name: 'Haley'}, {name: 'Ella'}, {name: 'Landon'}, {name: 'John'}
        ];
    };
```

This also can be done using `$inject` also

```
angular.module('app')
        .controller('myApp',myApp);

    myApp.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function myApp($scope) {
          var vm = this;
          vm.title = 'Customers';
          vm.customers = [
            {name: 'Haley'}, {name: 'Ella'}, {name: 'Landon'}, {name: 'John'}
            ];
        };
```